# Customising donut color on Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to customise the color of values in my donut chart. For eg in the below screenshot I'd like for the Chrome field to be green instead.

[donut chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJNxe.png)

From my research it seems this feature was recently introduced however I can't seem to find the functionality on my platform. I haven't seen anything specific about donut charts in their documentation.